# Pymongo date range(same date with different time) query returns no results

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Im newbie for pymongo, I want to get data between given datetime object.I gave same date with different time means it returns no result if i gave different date means show the results.I don't know why? So, Please anyone help to me. Im using MongoDB Compass, here ISODate not available in MongoDB Compass only Date object So, I don't want ISODate.Anyone guide to me.

Here my code:

```
    start = datetime.datetime(2017,11,17,10,00,23)
    end = datetime.datetime(2017,11,17,14,00,56)
    data = db.datapoints.find({'res_date':{'$gte':start,'$lte':end }})
```

Mongo document like this:

```
{
  _id:5a0c06aacff7580001e10fc9
  res_value:"1"
  line_code:"1"
  res_date:2017-11-17 10:36:40.564
  res_code:"1"
}
{
    _id:5a0e6fcc409d8f00017f477c
    res_value:"23"
    line_code:"22"
    res_date:2017-11-17 10:42:44.145
    res_code:"22"
 }
 {
    _id:5a0e6fcc409d8f00017f477c
    res_value:"243"
    line_code:"224"
    res_date:2017-11-17 12:07:07.496
    res_code:"223"
 }
 {
    _id:5a0e6fcc409d8f00017f477c
    res_value:"253"
    line_code:"225"
    res_date:2017-11-17 12:23:32.936
    res_code:"522"
 }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the type of your res_date? Is it an ISODate() ? Cause it doesn’t look like it

Comment: No.. Its just date

Comment: Can you solve my issues

Comment: have you tried querying the date range directly in your mongo database?

Comment: yeah... but it empty result set if compare same date with different time(I want to get last three hours record)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't added a particular offset mongodb stores date always in UTC.

I tried to follow trough with the input data that you gave. So that is the data that I added (Its same as yours):

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0c06aacff7580001e10fc9"), 
    "res_value" : "1", 
    "line_code" : "1", 
    "res_date" : ISODate("2017-11-17T10:36:40.564+0000"), 
    "res_code" : "1"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0e6fcc409d8f00017f477c"), 
    "res_value" : "23", 
    "line_code" : "22", 
    "res_date" : ISODate("2017-11-17T10:42:44.145+0000"), 
    "res_code" : "22"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1427c36c9b762bd4961f30"), 
    "res_value" : "243", 
    "line_code" : "224", 
    "res_date" : ISODate("2017-11-17T12:07:07.496+0000"), 
    "res_code" : "223"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1427d46c9b762bd4961f35"), 
    "res_value" : "253", 
    "line_code" : "225", 
    "res_date" : ISODate("2017-11-17T12:23:32.936+0000"), 
    "res_code" : "522"
}
```

And with this data and this query:

```
db.collectionName.find(
{
  'res_date':{'$gte': ISODate("2017-11-17T10:00:23.564+0000"),
              '$lte': ISODate("2017-11-17T14:00:56.564+0000") }
})
```

I get all 4 as results.

I think the problem is not with your mongodb but in your code itself. Check out this blog https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2015/python-and-timezones

> Always use aware datetime object, i.e. with timezone information. That
>   makes sure you can compare them directly (aware and unaware datetime
>   objects are not comparable) and will return them correctly to users.
>   Leverage pytz to have timezone objects.

Note also in the link I added:

> If you need to store those timestamps, the same rule should apply. If
>   you rely on MongoDB, it assumes that all the timestamp are in UTC, so
>   be careful when storing them – you will have to normalize the
>   timestamp to UTC.

Try querying with both use cases. Here is an example

```
import datetime
import pytz

startUnaware= datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 10, 00, 23)
endUnaware= datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 14, 00, 56)
dataUnaware = db.datapoints.find({'res_date':{'$gte':startUnaware,'$lte':endUnaware }})

startAware = datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 10, 00, 23, pytz.UTC)
endAware = datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 14, 00, 56, pytz.UTC)
dataAware = db.datapoints.find({'res_date':{'$gte':startAware,'$lte':endAware }})
```

Comment: I have So many documents in my db... im just show format of my document for example.. In my code, im put static date i have document in between that range of date. but, it empty result

Comment: Oh okay, just thought you added the document you were expecting as result as example

Comment: Both queries not working.. First queries as usual given empty result, second one given import error. i import pytz but shows "Unable to import module" error.

Comment: This problem is off topic. There are solutions on how to install pytz and if you can’t find any then ask a new question with this topic.